# Access a column of DF that is in list in Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of DataFrames and I would like to access one or multiple columns of a particular DataFrame.
List of DataFrames (dfs):

```
[                   
var1       var1  
14.171250  13.593813
13.578317  13.595329
10.301850  13.598456
9.930217   12.682156
6.192517   13.561943
10.89585  13.565149
6.197983   13.572509,  

var1       var2    
2.456183  5.907528
5.052017  5.955731
5.960000  5.972480
8.039317  5.984608
7.559217  5.985348
6.933633  5.979438,

var1       var1  
14.171250  23.593813
23.578317  23.595329
56.301850  23.580139
90.930217  22.365676
89.192517  33.561943
86.23654   53.565149
90.63659   13.572509,  
...]
```

Now, I would like to access `var2` column in my second DataFrame.

I tried the following,

```
for i, h in enumerate(dfs):
    for col in i[1]:
        colum = col['var2']
print(colum)
```

Above code does not work. How can I access `var2` of the second indexed DataFrame?

Comment: `i` is an auto-incrementing integer. `h` is the item in the enumerated list.

Comment: i thought `i` gives the index??

Comment: So, you want `dfs[1].loc[:, 'var2']`

Comment: `for x, y in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])`.... `x` will take the values 0, 1, 2 and `y` will take the values `a`, `b`, `c`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, `dfs[1].loc[:, 'var2']` this gives all the DataFrames, but I need just the second DataFrame

Comment: @i.n.n.m dfs[1] gives the second, if `dfs` is your list

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, I was missing `[1]`, now it works charm!

Comment: @i.n.n.m Added an explanation as to why your code didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `dfs` is your list of dataframes.

*Option 1:* Direct indexing:

```
var2 = dfs[1]['var2']
```

*Option 2:* Using `df.loc` (explicit):

```
var2 = dfs[1].loc[:, 'var2']
```

---

*Option 3:* Using `df.iloc` (index based - implicit):

```
var2 = dfs[1].iloc[:, 1]  # assuming `var2` is the second column
```

---

#### What's wrong with your code?

`enumerate` returns an (index, item) tuple at each iteration. So, in your code, `i` is the index and `h` is the element (dataframe).

```
for i, h in enumerate(dfs):
    for col in i[1]:
        colum = col['var2']
```

`i[1]` will throw a `TypeError` error. You would need

```
for i, h in enumerate(dfs):
    if i == 1:
        column = h['var2']
        break
```

If you need only the data frame, you can drop the loop and just use `dfs[1]`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED `column = h['var2']` how do I access the second DF?

Comment: @i.n.n.m Modified my answer. But I don't recommend you do that. use one of the above 3 methods.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, this explains now why it throws a type error. what if I have to loop through it and plot them for each `DF`s `var2` values?

Comment: @i.n.n.m I am not well versed with plotting. But you'd probably plot each one in the loop (remove the if i == 1 and break) and then plt.show() at the end.